# Xpages How to set default value to blank field after document has already been saved?

Tags: xpages, el

My PCModel document will go through several workflow processes, and the user will only add the necessary information at the appropriate stage. The user will select a dialogbox and be presented with a few fields.

For some of these fields I want to pre-populate a default value. However, my fields are bound to my Java object. and default code is ignored, I believe because there ALREADY is a value in the field, blank.

How can I add a default value, like the current user, to the bound field while still allowing the user to override this?

```
<xc:cc_CommonFormField id="cc_CommonFormField7" fieldName="buildUser" label="By Team Member">
   <xp:this.facets>
       <xp:comboBox id="comboBoxA" xp:key="field" value="#{PCModel.buildUser}"
defaultValue="#{userBean.commonName}">

<xp:selectItems>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Select A Value|"}]]></xp:this.value>

</xp:selectItems>
<xp:selectItems
value="#{PCConfig.networkTeam}"/>
</xp:comboBox>
</xp:this.facets>
</xc:cc_CommonFormField>
```

My java object is normal.

Comment: Add the logic to the getter of the field so that it returns the default value if the field is empty/blank?

Comment: I was thinking about doing that. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize the value in your Java bean

*or*

set the value somewhere in your SSJS code with

```
PCModel.buildUser = userBean.commonName
```

Comment: Both of these worked. I decided to go with setting it in the SSJS, if made more sense as I also had to make sure the document was in the correct stage, and that is easier to do in the button.

Comment: Bryan - it's easier to do in the button BUT, the code for that button can call a java method.  so I strongly suggest you put any logic like this into java.  Keep it off you're XPage itself.  all my pages have a java object associated with it acting as a "pageController".  This is a great way to do things like this.